# Navigate from UIViewController to SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swiftui

I see a lot online about how to *navigate to* a UIViewController *from* a SwiftUI view, but not much on how to navigate *from* a UIViewController *to* a SwiftUI view. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this as you do with `UIViewcontroller`, But SwiftUIView is represented with `UIHostingController` in `UIKit`

```swift
import SwiftUI
    
...

let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: YourSwiftUIView())
navigationController?.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Does it work? Can I see the code?